# Why do the pictures attached to my seeded items not display on Heroku (ERROR 500)?

Tags: image, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, seeding

First-time poster, I tried to follow the rules but please tell me if anything is missing and/or needs to be edited in this question.

## TL;DR :  using `ActiveStorage`, pictures associated to items display fine on localhost but not on Heroku

## Initial setup

In an educational context, my team and I are building a simple Ruby On Rails application. We have to use `Ruby 2.5.1` and `Rails 5.2.4` with a `postgresql 9.5` database in development, and we have to use Heroku for production.

The source code is hosted on a GitLab instance name [Framagit](https://framagit.org/ok-compost/thp-okcompost). We are using the GitLab pipeline to deploy the code to [Heroku](https://ok-compost-staging.herokuapp.com/) everytime a merge is completed in the `staging` branch.
`Procfile` is as follows :

```
realease: rails db:migrate && rails db:seed
web: rails server
```

On this app, the main model is `Compost`. Each instance has one picture. These pictures are stored under :

```
app/assets/images/compost_pictures/compost_{001-007}.jpg
```

## ActiveStorage setup

`ActiveStorage` has been installed by running `$ rails active_storage:install` followed by `$ rails db:migrate` which created the `active_storage_attachments` and `active_storage_blobs` tables in `db/schema.rb`.

`app/models/compost.rb` was updated with :

```rb
  # Active Storage picture association
  has_one_attached :picture
```

`app/views/composts/show.html.erb` now includes :

```html
<div class="col-8">
  <% if @compost.picture.attached? %>
    <%= image_tag @compost.picture, style:"height: auto; max-width:100%" %>
  <% else %>
    <h3> Hey, why don't you provide a nice compost picture ?</h3>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

(also tried with `image_tag url_for(@compost.picture)` with no success on Heroku, although it works on localhost)
(`@compost` is set in the controller and works fine for other composts attributes display)

and `db/seeds.rb` was updated with :

```rb
def compost_seed(user)
    new_compost = user.owned_composts.create!( all the attributes...)
    picture_file_name = 'compost_' + (format '%03d', rand(1..7)) + '.jpg'
    picture_path = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "compost_pictures", picture_file_name)
    new_compost.picture.attach(
      io: File.open(picture_path),
      filename: picture_file_name,
      content_type: "image/jpg"
    )
  end
```

## Running the server

### Locally

On `localhost` with the `Rails server` set to `development`, everything works fine, pictures are displayed.
I've set up a simulated production environment like this :

```sh
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails db:create db:migrate
# completed with no error

$ RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
# completed with no error

$ RAILS_ENV=production rails db:seed
# completed with no error

$ RAILS_ENV=production SERVE_STATIC_ASSETS=true rails server
# server runs smoothly
```

Everything works fine, pictures are displayed.

### On Heroku

- none of the pictures is displayed : they are replaced by a broken image symbol
- when in Heroku `rails console`, `> Compost.all.sample.picture.attached?` returns `true`
- in the browser, the URL of the image is `https://ok-compost-staging.herokuapp.com/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWRaV2huZW1SRGVESkRTRE5sWWxoSGJYSlJSakpTVG5OVUJqb0dSVlE2RUdScGMzQnZjMmwwYVc5dVNTSkphVzVzYVc1bE95Qm1hV3hsYm1GdFpUMGlZMjl0Y0c5emRGOHdNRFl1YW5Cbklqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5ZGpiMjF3YjNOMFh6QXdOaTVxY0djR093WlVPaEZqYjI1MFpXNTBYM1I1Y0dWSklnOXBiV0ZuWlM5cWNHVm5CanNHVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMTktMTItMDdUMDA6NDM6NTUuNTYzWiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--ee616a99d031d361f2b63aeb869ca5d787ef44a8/compost_006.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22compost_006.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27compost_006.jpg` and trying to visit it ends up with a 'We're sorry, but something went wrong'.
  The logs are :

```sh
2019-12-07T00:44:44.433822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWRVMVI1ZERoQ1ZXUlFibUpTTVZGNFRWbEVUamhaVldsMkJqb0dSVlE2RUdScGMzQnZjMmwwYVc5dVNTSkphVzVzYVc1bE95Qm1hV3hsYm1GdFpUMGlZMjl0Y0c5emRGOHdNREV1YW5Cbklqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5ZGpiMjF3YjNOMFh6QXdNUzVxY0djR093WlVPaEZqYjI1MFpXNTBYM1I1Y0dWSklnOXBiV0ZuWlM5cWNHVm5CanNHVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMTktMTItMDdUMDA6NDk6MzcuMzI2WiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--cae4ff5349cfa4a394c081da5827f0c35ce96c08/compost_001.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22compost_001.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27compost_001.jpg" host=ok-compost-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=e8ca9a03-07c4-459d-ab20-4e096da30e87 fwd="78.201.127.110" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2019-12-07T00:44:47.277080+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T00:44:47.276974 #4]  INFO -- : [f8400596-5b61-4569-ad22-b514afe4b32a] Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWRVMVI1ZERoQ1ZXUlFibUpTTVZGNFRWbEVUamhaVldsMkJqb0dSVlE2RUdScGMzQnZjMmwwYVc5dVNTSkphVzVzYVc1bE95Qm1hV3hsYm1GdFpUMGlZMjl0Y0c5emRGOHdNREV1YW5Cbklqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5ZGpiMjF3YjNOMFh6QXdNUzVxY0djR093WlVPaEZqYjI1MFpXNTBYM1I1Y0dWSklnOXBiV0ZuWlM5cWNHVm5CanNHVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMTktMTItMDdUMDA6NDk6MzcuMzI2WiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--cae4ff5349cfa4a394c081da5827f0c35ce96c08/compost_001.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22compost_001.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27compost_001.jpg" for 78.201.127.110 at 2019-12-07 00:44:47 +0000
2019-12-07T00:44:47.277980+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T00:44:47.277897 #4]  INFO -- : [f8400596-5b61-4569-ad22-b514afe4b32a] Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
2019-12-07T00:44:47.278103+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T00:44:47.278010 #4]  INFO -- : [f8400596-5b61-4569-ad22-b514afe4b32a]   Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"compost_001.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''compost_001.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWRVMVI1ZERoQ1ZXUlFibUpTTVZGNFRWbEVUamhaVldsMkJqb0dSVlE2RUdScGMzQnZjMmwwYVc5dVNTSkphVzVzYVc1bE95Qm1hV3hsYm1GdFpUMGlZMjl0Y0c5emRGOHdNREV1YW5Cbklqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5ZGpiMjF3YjNOMFh6QXdNUzVxY0djR093WlVPaEZqYjI1MFpXNTBYM1I1Y0dWSklnOXBiV0ZuWlM5cWNHVm5CanNHVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMTktMTItMDdUMDA6NDk6MzcuMzI2WiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--cae4ff5349cfa4a394c081da5827f0c35ce96c08", "filename"=>"compost_001"}
2019-12-07T00:44:47.279105+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T00:44:47.279040 #4]  INFO -- : [f8400596-5b61-4569-ad22-b514afe4b32a] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2019-12-07T00:44:47.279772+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-12-07T00:44:47.279702 #4] FATAL -- : [f8400596-5b61-4569-ad22-b514afe4b32a]
2019-12-07T00:44:47.279842+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-12-07T00:44:47.279773 #4] FATAL -- : [f8400596-5b61-4569-ad22-b514afe4b32a] Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_mtime - /app/storage/ST/yt/STyt8BUdPnbR1QxMYDN8YUiv)
```

- The images were properly displayed when we fetched them via their URL in the assets pipeline.

## So, what now ?

According to the logs, we guess this is a path issue. What are we missing ? At what point are we mistaken ?
We'll update the post with any required code snippet or test result, this is an educational project and nothing about it is private or sensitive.
Any insight or pointer appreciated :)

## Workaround : use cloud storage instead of local disk in production

Since all the other images (background, logos, etc.) were displayed properly, the problem had to lie with our Active Storage use.

According to [Heroku doc on Active Storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku) they use Ephemeral Disks for Active Storage and files are not persisted neither across dyno nor over time. So our guess was that our attachments were not stored on the dyno that served our application.

Connecting the production storage to a free-tier AWS bucket as suggested in Heroku doc worked for us and images are displayed properly.

Comment: @ Gaël, did you ever figure this out?  I have a pretty much identical problem, localhost works fine but broken image icons in production.

Comment: @AaronParisi more or less, I just edited the original post.